# Replace nan values to Null in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I'm reading data from multiple CSV files that have dynamic columns using Pandas. Many of them contain nan values, including a few date columns. I want to replace only the nan values in the date columns with Null values. None, 'Null', and '' values are not allowed by the Postgres query.

**Tried solutions :**

- setting None wont work for the postgres query it has to be Null.
- setting 'Null' also wont work.
- doesn't worked df.fillna('')

**goal is to insert dataframe data into the postgres table using insert query.
allow Null values in the postgres date column.**

Answer (score 0):

First try to get columns then apply fill nan like bellow.

```
col = df.columns 
for rec in col:
    df['rec'] = df['rec'].fillna('Null')
```

Comment: We can not hardcode the column names they are dynamic and all the CSV files don't have a date column. even though it will replace it as Null with a single quote ('Null'). which will cause the same issue.

Comment: It is not hardcode column , when you do the df.columns it give all columns name in list and it is dyanmic,then using that list we get each columns any apply condition what we want